# Marklogic how does secondary sort order works?

Tags: marklogic

How does secondary sort order works, can someone elaborate on the same?
As documents are already sorted by primary sort order, will the secondary sort order work on elements with same score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documents with the same primary score will be sorted within that group by the secondary score.

It’s just like sorting people by last name then first name. People with the same last name get sorted within that group by their first name.

Comment: Just wanted to know one more use case, what will be search order for empty search

Comment: or search result with same score?

Comment: An empty search will still use document quality to give score to returned results. For documents with a tied score I believe MarkLogic is free to return those results in any order it pleases.

Comment: so there is no concrete definition of ordering in that case right?

Comment: What ordering would you expect? They're literally tied. I predict (but haven't tested) that the results will be stable meaning the same on repeated execution (because there's probably an internal sort order used based on the hash of the URIs) but there's no guarantee of that remaining so in future product versions. The database is free to return something else if it's faster.